# AS3 - "\u2605" NOT the same as "\\u"+"2605"?

Tags: string, actionscript-3, actionscript

Trying to make a textfield where people write the unicode without the backslash. I want to add the backslash after they typed it. So the user types u2605 and the code converts it to "\u2605", i then convert this to a unicode character and insert it in textflow.

My code:

- this works:

  ```
  span.text = publicFunctions.htmlUnescape(he.encode("\u2605"))
  ```
- this doesn't work:

  ```
  span.text = publicFunctions.htmlUnescape(he.encode("\\u"+"2605"))
  ```

how to make a string that acts as a unicode string?

Tried all sorts of things, `escape(unescape())`, convert to number, "\u", "\u" ... nothing helps.

trace("\u2605" == "\u"+"2605")  ... will return false. So will
trace("\u2605" == "\u"+"2605")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"\u2605"` is a string with a single character, the character with the code point `2605`, while `"\\u" + "2605"` is a string with 6 characters (the backslash, the `u` and the four digit number).

If you want to construct a unicode character from just the four digits, you should be able to use [`String.fromCharCode`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#fromCharCode%28%29). The thing is just that the escape sequence uses a [hexadecimal](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ef8.html) number, while the method obviously takes a decimal number. So if the user enters a hexadecimal string, you will have to convert that first:

```
trace(String.fromCharCode(parseInt('2605', 16)) == '\u2605'));
```

Comment: Doesn't work 
String.fromCharCode(2605) = rectangle
'\u2605' = Star
trace(String.fromCharCode(2605) == '\u2605')) returns false

Comment: Totally worked :D Wouldn't have thought about this solution. Thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 0):

That's an interesting issue! I don't think you can concatenate a string literal and achieve what you're trying to do. The relevant character escaping happens when the string literal is originally formed, which means that you need the whole sequence together in the first place.

But you should be able to take the user-supplied number and dynamically generate a Unicode string with `String.fromCharCode(...)`.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#fromCharCode()

Comment: Tried that, i don't think i have the number if the user types in u2605 ... this is a star. and String.fromCharCode(2605) is a rectangle.